# First object jumps on re-entry of second colliding object

Tags: unity, c#

The scenario is that I have two objects - Object A and Object B. The Object A is lying on the ground and when Object B enters the collider of Object A, the Object A moves (only X and Z axis) with Object B. The movement works well with the script shown below.

The issue is that most of the time, the Object A's initially position shifts by few meters whenever Object B enters its collider. I feel it is related to offset position. What should happen is that, Object A should be the same position when Object B enters the collider and move along with Object B only when Object B moves.

So how do I fix this?

````
private Vector3 offsetPosition;

public Transform ObjectB;

public bool ObjectB_Collision = false;

void Start () {
        offsetPosition = ObjectB.transform.position - this.transform.position;
    }

    void ObjectB_HasEntered() {
        offsetPosition = ObjectB.transform.position - this.transform.position;
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate () {

        if (ObjectB_Collision == true) {
            this.transform.position = new Vector3 (ObjectB.transform.position.x, this.transform.position.y, ObjectB.transform.position.z) - new Vector3 (offsetPosition.x, 0, offsetPosition.z);
        }

    }

public void OnTriggerEnter (Collider col) {
        if (!enabled) return;

        if (col.gameObject.name == "Object_B") {
            ObjectB_HasEntered();
            ObjectB_Collision = true;
        }
    }


public void OnTriggerExit (Collider col) {
        if (!enabled) return;

       if (col.gameObject.name == "Object_B") {
            ObjectB_Collision = false;

        }
    }
```
````

Comment: The usual advice here is "don't move physics objects with transform.position" — that's handled as removing the object from the physics scene, teleporting it, and re-adding it, which can cause all kinds of unwanted behaviour. Have you tried moving this object via its Rigidbody instead?

Comment: @DMGregory Basically the first object moves along the same axis/direction as the second object. Which I am achieving through transform.position. How does one get the same behavior with rigidbody?

Comment: Did you read the API or search for previous Q&A answering that? They'll be able to answer you faster — I'm still making breakfast.

Comment: @DMGregory Looks like he is moving ObjectA completely manually, not relying on the physics engine for B to push A.

Comment: @Saif If both objects have a Rigidbody, it's possible that the Rigidbody is getting pushed and having its own velocity in addition to your custom code. Otherwise, there may be a problem with the offset that you're measuring when the collision occurs. You might try using a smaller offset. Or remove your custom movement code and rely on the physics engine for pushing.